# Can I add a button to my add-in next to Send/Discard buttons?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, office-app

I am writing an Outlook Add-In (Web version, Desktop) and so far I was able to add a link to my app in the contextual menu (see screenshot below - highlighted in yellow). This work well, but it is almost impossible to find the add-in and this is resulting in a ton of customer support calls. I was wondering if there is a way to add the button next to "Send", "Discard", or after the "Elipsis" buttons. This way the add-in would be more visible.

I was thinking about directly modifying the DOM if it is not possible, but I would prefer to not do that.

[image]

Comment: The user is allowed to pin the add-in when it is installed. As of now add-ins cannot be pinned through Manifest file. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins

Answer (score 2):

You can add a button there neither from a web based JS addin nor from a COM based addin for the desktop version of Outlook.

Comment: @ETL No, that would be double negative - neither/nor is used.